# Adding a number of rows to another worksheet based on cell value on a certain column

Tags: excel, vba, copy, rows

I am new to VBA, but had a situation where doing this manually would be extremely tedious, so I got to learning.

I needed a script that can find certain text values on a column and then copy a certain number of rows with all the row values into another worksheet. Full row values on the first row, and first 5 rows on the next rows. The text value that is searched is for example "DOL-1" or "VFD".

After lots of research and trial and error, I have managed to stitch together this script that does the job, but it is obviously badly written and not optimized. I have tried searching for similar questions and tried their answers, but I couldn't get anything to do what this script does.

I was wondering if there are some better and/or faster methods to achieve the same thing as this script does?

```
Sub Add_Rows()

Dim wbC As Workbook
Dim wbP As Workbook
Dim wsC As Worksheet
Dim wsP As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim r As Integer
Dim dataTable As Range

r = 8
'rownumber

Set wbP = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Projects\Feed_list.xlsx")
Set wsP = wbP.Worksheets("Feed_list")
' set paste destination (these variables aren't really even used because I couldn't get them to work)

Set wbC = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Projects\Generated_list.xlsm")
Set wsC = wbC.Worksheets("GEN")
' set copy location (these variables aren't really even used because I couldn't get them to work)

Windows("Generated_list.xlsm").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each cell In Range("AB2:AB5000")

    If cell.Value = "DOL-1" Then

        Debug.Print cell.Address
        Windows("Generated_list.xlsm").Activate
        Range(cell, cell.Offset(, -25)).Copy 
        Windows("Feed_list.xlsx").Activate
        Sheets("Feed_list").Select

        'Debug.Print r

        Rows(r).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        r = r + 1
        Rows(r).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        r = r + 1
        Rows(r).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        r = r + 1
        Rows(r).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        r = r + 1

        Windows("Generated_list.xlsm").Activate
        Range(cell.Offset(, -21), cell.Offset(, -25)).Copy
        Windows("Feed_list.xlsx").Activate
        Sheets("Feed_list").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

        Windows("Generated_list.xlsm").Activate
        Range(cell.Offset(, -21), cell.Offset(, -25)).Copy
        Windows("Feed_list.xlsx").Activate
        Sheets("Feed_list").Select
        Selection.Offset(-1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

        Windows("Generated_list.xlsm").Activate
        Range(cell.Offset(, -21), cell.Offset(, -25)).Copy
        Windows("Feed_list.xlsx").Activate
        Sheets("Feed_list").Select
        'Rows(r).Select
        Selection.Offset(-1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

    End If

    If cell.Value = "VFD" Then

        Debug.Print cell.Address
        Windows("Generated_list.xlsm").Activate
        Range(cell, cell.Offset(, -25)).Copy
        Windows("Feed_list.xlsx").Activate
        Sheets("Feed_list").Select

        'Debug.Print r

        Rows(r).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        r = r + 1
        Rows(r).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        r = r + 1

        Windows("Generated_list.xlsm").Activate
        Range(cell.Offset(, -21), cell.Offset(, -25)).Copy
        Windows("Feed_list.xlsx").Activate
        Sheets("Feed_list").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

        Windows("Generated_list.xlsm").Activate
        Range(cell.Offset(, -21), cell.Offset(, -25)).Copy
        Windows("Feed_list.xlsx").Activate
        Sheets("Feed_list").Select
        Selection.Offset(-1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

    End If

'these if functions are repeated about 20 times with different text values and number of rows copied

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Windows("Feed_list.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Feed_list").Select

End Sub
```

I made small example pictures. The Generated_list [looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg7SP.png) (Notice column AB)

The Feed_list [looks like this at first.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v89g7.png)

And after running the script it should [look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFura.png)

Comment: I'd point you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), if you haven't given it a read already.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Sub Main()
    Call Add_Rows(8)
End Sub

Sub Add_Rows(whereToAdd As Long)
    Dim wb_Feed As Workbook, wb_Gen As Workbook
    Dim ws_Feed As Worksheet, ws_Gen As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, i As Long, idxType As Long

    Set wb_Feed = Workbooks.Open("C:\Projects\Feed_list.xlsx")
    Set wb_Gen = Workbooks.Open("C:\Projects\Generated_list.xlsm")

    Set ws_Feed = wb_Feed.Worksheets("Feed_List")
    Set ws_Gen = wb_Gen.Worksheets("Generated_List")


    ' Find the last row and last column of the data in Generated List
    ' Assume that the first column does not contain any blank data in middle
    lastRow = ws_Gen.Cells(ws_Gen.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = ws_Gen.Cells(1, ws_Gen.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column    ' First row is header

    ' Column AB is the last column
    idxType = lastCol

    With ws_Gen
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If .Cells(i, idxType).Value = "VFD" Then
                ' Insert a row to Feed List
                ws_Feed.Range("A" & whereToAdd).EntireRow.Insert

                ' Copy entire row
                .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, lastCol)).Copy
                ' Paste
                ws_Feed.Range("A" & whereToAdd).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                ' Since VFD, insert extra 1 line according to your screenshot
                whereToAdd = whereToAdd + 1
                ws_Feed.Range("A" & whereToAdd).EntireRow.Insert

                ' Copy first 5 columns
                .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 5)).Copy
                ' Paste
                ws_Feed.Range("A" & whereToAdd).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                ' Update where to add next
                whereToAdd = whereToAdd + 1

            ElseIf .Cells(i, idxType).Value = "DOL-1" Then
                ' Insert a row to Feed List
                ws_Feed.Range("A" & whereToAdd).EntireRow.Insert

                ' Copy entire row
                .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, lastCol)).Copy
                ' Paste
                ws_Feed.Range("A" & whereToAdd).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                ' Since DOL-1 insert extra 3 lines according to your screenshot
                whereToAdd = whereToAdd + 1
                ws_Feed.Range("A" & whereToAdd).EntireRow.Insert
                ws_Feed.Range("A" & whereToAdd).EntireRow.Insert
                ws_Feed.Range("A" & whereToAdd).EntireRow.Insert

                ' Copy first 5 columns
                .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 5)).Copy
                ws_Feed.Range("A" & whereToAdd).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                ws_Feed.Range("A" & whereToAdd + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                ws_Feed.Range("A" & whereToAdd + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                ' Update where to add next
                whereToAdd = whereToAdd + 3
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    ' You should close the workbook after you finish your job
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error on `Set ws_Gen = wb_Gen.Worksheets("Generated_List")`. Run-time error '9'. Subscript out of range.

Comment: Can you check the name of the worksheet inside the workbook. For me, I named it Generated_List but it may be different for you so you should change the names based on what you have. I think in your case you should change it to "GEN"

Comment: Ah, yes of course. I changed that and now it seems to work perfectly. I will have to test it later on bigger scale, but I think I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer. Thank you!